# JMeter Grafana - How to get success, failed request count from JMeter into Grafana

Tags: jmeter, graphite, grafana

We are running a performance test using JMeter with a connection to Graphite via a backend listener. Connected to Graphite, we are using Grafana to display the real time performance metrics such as active users, max response time, several percentiles and number 'all', 'success' and 'fail' requests.

All metrics are displayed according to expectation except for the 'all', 'success' and 'fail' requests. The number of requests displayed in Grafana (and Graphite) is way below the expected numbers. For example, we only get 28 responses (for all) in Grafana while 1440 are expected.

To narrow the problem, let me focus just on the all request metric. In order to display this metric I am using "all.a.count". Screenshots of the JMeter Backend listener, and a screenshot taken from Grafana are included below.

[Backend Listener JMeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp7OW.png)

[Results in Grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYcwK.png)

What am I doing wrong here? What is needed to get the expected number of 1440 requests in Grafana?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: what is the resolution in graphite? show graphite's storage-files.conf. how often metrics are sent? By default graphite resolution is 1 minute. If jmeter updates metric, every seconds, it is possible that each value is overwritten, you end up only with last one.